# jQuery variable with children

Tags: jquery

How to use this? I am studying the jQuery Cookbook and I'm new. I can't figure out on how to make this code work.

```
var anchors = jQuery('a');
// #1
anchors.children();
// #2
jQuery('> *', anchors);
// #3
anchors.find('> *');
```

The thing is, I'm trying to select all the child `<a>` tags on the list using the variable and children which is the code above according to the cookbook.

This is the HTML code:

```
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="#anchor1">Anchor 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#anchor2">Anchor 2</a></li>
<li><span><a href="#anchor3">Anchor 3</a></span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: why not just use (ul#nav li a)?

Comment: i did that, but i want to try some other structures like those 3

Comment: What is `anchors` referring to?

Comment: it's a variable, sorry for not adding it earlier

Comment: Your `a` tags have no children. What do you expect to select ?

Comment: you couldn't select anything because a tag is already selected by anchor variable, all three motheds select the child of a tag.

Comment: think about what you are trying to do: you have selected all 'a-tags' on the page, now you want only the ones having a `ul#nav` as parent. What you try to do in your current code is find children of all selected 'a-tags' ... well they don't have children..

Comment: yup i know that a has no child, what i mean is, how could i use the following:

anchors.children();

jQuery('> *', anchors);

anchors.find('> *');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you would like to use these statements:

```
var list = jQuery('ul#nav');
// #1
list.children();
// #2
jQuery('> *', list);
// #3
list.find('> *');
```

all 3 resuting in the 3 list items ('li')

Here's a fiddles: (nice tool to try stuff out and show people what your question is about)

http://jsfiddle.net/h8ayT/

http://jsfiddle.net/h8ayT/1/